# Changing the layout of the ipython widgets toggle buttons

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

These are the buttons that I'm trying to customize:
[image: toggle buttons from ipywidgets]

The [code](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#ToggleButton) itself.

---

This is the result I want to get (edited by GIMP):

[image: edit]

---

I want to keep these buttons stacked vertically (as shown in the edited image I made), but since I don't know much about CSS, I don't know how to do that. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please post your code in text, not an image.

Comment: it's not my code. I got it from the documentation (I added the link in the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Bananach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68246138/4752223) said, `layout=widgets.Layout(width='100px')` will do it.

```
widgets.ToggleButtons(
    options=['A','B', 'C'],
    disabled=False,
    button_style='info', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    layout=widgets.Layout(width='100px')
    #     icons=['check'] * 3
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this explicitly, but if you pass `layout=dict(width='200px')` to the `ToggleButtons` constructor, the widget will automatically stack the buttons vertically to be able to fit them in the given width.